# Why doesn't this assignment throw a ReferenceError?

Tags: javascript, reference, language-lawyer

Consider three cases, where both `a` and `k` are undefined:

```
if (a) console.log(1); // ReferenceError
```

and

```
var a = k || "value"; // ReferenceError
```

seems reasonable, but...

```
var a = a || "value"; // "value"
```

Why doesn't the last case throw a `ReferenceError`? Isn't `a` being referenced before it's defined?

Comment: @Deep read again please

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because of one of `var`'s "features" called [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting). Per the link:

> Because variable declarations (and declarations in general) are processed before any code is executed, **declaring a variable anywhere in the code is equivalent to declaring it at the top**. This also means that a variable can appear to be used before it's declared. This behavior is called "hoisting", **as it appears that the variable declaration is moved to the top of the function or global code.** (emphasis mine)

So, for example:

```
console.log(a);
var a = "foo";
```

Instead of throwing a `ReferenceError` as you might expect, since `a` is referenced before it is defined, it logs `undefined`. This is because, as mentioned earlier, the declaration is processed first and essentially happens at the top, which means it's the same as:

```
var a;
console.log(a);
a = "foo";
```

The same goes for functions as mentioned earlier:

```
function foo() {
    console.log(a);
    var a = "foo";
}
```

That's the same as:

```
function foo() {
    var a;
    console.log(a);
    a = "foo";
}
```

To see why, look into the [ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-variable-statement):

> ### 13.3.2 Variable Statement
>
> NOTE
>
> A `var` statement declares variables that are scoped to [the running execution context’s *VariableEnvironment*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-execution-contexts). **Var variables are created when their containing [Lexical Environment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-lexical-environments) is instantiated and are initialized to `undefined` when created.**
>
> [...]
>
> A variable defined by a *`VariableDeclaration`* with an *`Initializer`* is assigned the **value of its *`Initializer`*’s *`AssignmentExpression`* when the *`VariableDeclaration`* is executed, not when the variable is created.** (emphasis mine)

From this, we can gather that the `var` declarations are created before any code is executed (in their lexical environment) and are scoped to the containing *`VariableEnvironment`*, which is either in the global scope, or in a function. They are initially given the value `undefined`. The next part explains that the value that the `var` is assigned to is the value of the right hand side when the declaration is executed, not when the variable is created.

This applies to your situation because in your example, `a` is referenced like it is in the example. Using the information earlier, your code:

```
var a = a || "value";
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
var a;
a = a || "value";
```

Remember that all declarations are processed before any code is executed. The JavaScript engine sees that there's a declaration, variable `a` and declares it at the top of the current function or global scope. It is then given the value `undefined`.  Since `undefined` is falsey, `a` is assigned to `value`.

In contrast, your second example throws a `ReferenceError`:

```
var a = k || "value";
```

It can also be rewritten as:

```
var a;
a = k || "value";
```

Now you see the problem. Since `k` is never a declared anywhere, no variable with that identifier exists. That means, unlike with `a` in the first example, `k` is never declared and throws the `ReferenceError` because it is referenced before declaration.

> But how do you explain `var a = "123"; var a = a || "124"; // a = "123"`?

From the ES2015 Language Specification again:

> Within the scope of any [VariableEnvironment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-execution-contexts) a common *`BindingIdentifier`* may appear in more than one *`VariableDeclaration`* but those declarations collective define only one variable.

To put it plainly: variables can be defined in the same function or global scope more than once, but always define the same variable. Thus, in your example:

```
var a = "123";
var a = a || "124";
```

It can be rewritten as:

```
var a;
a = "123";
a = a || "124";
```

Declaring `a` **in the same function or global scope** again collectively only declares it once. `a` is assigned to `"123"`, then it is assigned to `"123"` again because `"123"` is truthy.

---

As of ES2015, you should, in my opinion, no longer use `var`. It has function scoping and can cause unexpected assignments like those mentioned in the question. Instead, if you still want mutability, try using `let`:

```
let a = a || "value";
```

This will throw a `ReferenceError`. Even though all variables are hoisted, no matter which declarator you use (`var`, `let`, or `const`), with `let` and `const` it is invalid to reference an uninitialized variable. Also, `let` and `const` have *block scope*, not *function scope*. This is more clear and normal regarding other languages:

```
function foo() {
    {
        var a = 3;
    }
    console.log(a); //logs 3
}
```

Versus:

```
function foo() {
    {
        let a = 3;
    }
    console.log(a); //ReferenceError
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = k || 'value';
var a = a || 'value';
```

a is declared when you call `var a` but k is not, that why first line is ReferenceError and second line is 'value'

Answer (score -2):

```
if (a) console.log(1); // ReferenceError
```

in this case i think there is no doubt as a is not declared anywhere before using it so refrence error

```
var a = k || "value"; //ReferenceError
```

same case here k is not declared and we are trying to use it

```
var a = a || "value"; //"value"
```

now in this case when we are trying use a (a in r.h.s) that time a is already declared before using it and hence no error

Adding to this if you want to know difference between reference error and undefined

refrence error -indicate variable is not declared yet whereas

undefined - it is special value  in javascript assigned to any variable as soon as it is declared  undefined indicates that variable is declared but has not taken any value